# Application icon is not getting displayed in control panel add/remove programs

Tags: c++, visual-studio, icons, control-panel

I have a c++ application.  The app icon shows fine on the start menu, task bar etc., but not in Add / Remove Programs in the control panel. What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Control panel add/remove program reads all the programs list from registry.

For XP it's HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

you can take backup of your registry, and remove your program name from this registry.

Comment: Thanks man..!! Dat has worked. DisplayIcon parameter was missing for my application. I have added it and the icon is getting displayed now. Thanks again.